# Drupal 6 exposing fields in views

Tags: entities, views

So I have a product content type with a title field and a file upload field and I created a bulk operation to enable the user to upload a single file, selecting which titles to upload that file for.

But what my client really wants is a page (instead of modifying each individual node) with a list of the product titles and a file upload next to each since most of the products use different files.  My view is defined with a table style instead of the bulk operations style and has the title field and the file upload field displayed but in the preview, the file upload field column only shows the file names for the titles which already have a file uploaded and the rest of the rows blank.

Is there a way to expose this file upload field like you do a filter so the user can upload a different file for each title ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some research, I was able to find [Editview](https://www.drupal.org/project/editview) for Drupal 6. I'm not quite sure if it's like how [Editable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) work for Drupal 7.

It states in the Editview's module page that,

> It allows you to create a view in which the nodes are editable, and
>   new nodes can be created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Nice find.  Even though it states that it only works for views 2, not views 3, and we are already on views 3, it seems to be working as hoped, although I do get an ajax error pop up on each save.  I'll continue to update this.

Comment: You're welcome! Oh! I was assuming you're using Views 6.x-2.18. Nice one! :)

Comment: The only other minor issue I have with this module is that there is no functionality to pick and choose which fields you want to be editable on the row.  All of the fields (in my case, four of them) on the row are data entry fields whereas I only wanted one of the fields to be that way and the rest be data display fields so the user can't accidentally modify a value that shouldn't be modified.

Comment: Hmm.. not so sure at the moment but since it may be a form, you could use hook_form_alter() to hide it or hide and disable the unwanted fields. I could check that module later though.